# how can I add animation to toggle effect in jquery and show the toggle on click

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I need to animate this toggle effect and hide the paragraph first. When a user clicks on the Toggle, it must show the paragraph. Else it needs to be hidden. This code shows the paragraph first and hides it when clicked on Toggle.

Here's the code I'm using. I copied it from w3schools.com with little bit of editing. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ab a").click(function(){
    $("#quick").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ab"><a href="#">Toggle</a></div>
<div id="quick">This is a paragraph with little content.</div>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean you want hide <div id="quick">This is a paragraph with little content.</div> by default?

Comment: how do you want to animate it? Fade? Translate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#quick').hide();
$(".ab a").click(function () {
    $("#quick").toggle('slow');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b85LE/)**

Comment: I copied exactly the same but it didn't happen

Comment: yup, I just did it. Thank you guys (Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ab a").click(function () {
    $("#quick").toggle('slow');
});
});
```

That should work. Have you checked your console (F12) to make sure jQuery is loading?